# create PDF from array of bytes using Aspose Pdf for java

Tags: java, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using an array of bytes, i'm using this code :

```
    byte[] input = content.getBytes();
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
    pdfDoc .save(output, SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

but im getting this error :

```
Incorect file format com.aspose.pdf.exceptions.InvalidPdfFileFormatException: Incorect file format
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p116.z6.m1(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p75.z26$z1.deserialize(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p115.z8.deserialize(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p109.z17.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p109.z17.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p79.z2.m1(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p109.z16.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p79.z2.m5(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p24.z13.m2(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p24.z13.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.m1(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.ADocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.pdf.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

please can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: Such errors occur when input file is not PDF format. The Document constructor expects PDF file as input argument.

Comment: I think, both the file you're reading, and the way you read it matter. Either the file could be corrupt in the first place or it could have been corrupted  by the reading process. So without looking at both of these this is hard to say what exactly is causing the issue. Though one option maybe as codewarior said above -- the file is not pdf file at all. So need to see both the code and input file.

Comment: thank you every one, the problem was because of my file, i changed the file and everthing went fine